# Tkinter button only sinks when pressed with a left click

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

Tkinter beginner here

I've been working on a virtual mouse project and I stumbled upon a small problem when creating the GUI that corresponds to mouse functions. Specifically, I have a function I want to perform when a UI button is clicked and the button to sink when pressed, while the others stay raised. The callback function works with every mouse button as intended, but **the issue is that the UI button will only sink when pressed with a left mouse click.**

Is there a way to make the UI buttons sink regardless of which mouse button I press? For example, I want to make a UI button sink by using the middle mouse button.

Here is my code, Using python 3.8:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

switch_frame = tk.Frame(root)
switch_frame.pack()



root.geometry("230x200")

def hh(event,):
    print('This works as intended with all the mouse buttons, but the UI button only sinks when pressed with a left click')
   

switch_variable = tk.StringVar(value="off")

b1 = tk.Radiobutton(switch_frame, text='Left Click',width=15,height=6,variable=switch_variable,indicatoron=False,value="left_click")
b2 = tk.Radiobutton(switch_frame, text='Right Click',width=15,height=6,variable=switch_variable,indicatoron=False,value="right_click")
b3 = tk.Radiobutton(switch_frame, text='Double Click',width=15,height=6,variable=switch_variable,indicatoron=False,value="double_click")
b4 = tk.Radiobutton(switch_frame, text='Middle Click',width=15,height=6,variable=switch_variable,indicatoron=False,value='middle_click')

#Used binding "<Button>" to bind the function with all mouse buttons
b1.bind("<Button>", hh)
b2.bind("<Button>", hh)
b3.bind("<Button>", hh)
b4.bind("<Button>", hh)



b1.grid(column=0, row=0)   
b2.grid(column=1, row=0)   
b3.grid(column=0, row=1)   
b4.grid(column=1, row=1)  

root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by "invoking" the `Radiobutton` widget that was clicked, which is one of the pieces of information contained in the `event` argument passed to your even-handler.

```
def hh(event,):
    print('This works as intended with *all* the mouse buttons.')
    event.widget.invoke()
```